# I need help figuring out how to fix the output when compute complex numbers

Tags: javascript, complex-numbers

JavaScript Code:

```
function ImaginaryNumbers(realNum, imaginary) {
    this.realNum = 0;
    this.imaginary = 0;
    this.realNum = (typeof realNum === 'undefined') ? this.realNum : parseFloat(realNum);
    this.imaginary = (typeof imaginary === 'undefined') ? this.imaginary : parseFloat(imaginary);  
}

ImaginaryNumbers.transform = function(num) {
    var imaginaryNumbers;
    imaginaryNumbers = (num instanceof ImaginaryNumbers) ? num : imaginaryNumbers;
    imaginaryNumbers = (typeof num === 'number') ? new ImaginaryNumbers(num, 0) : num;
    return imaginaryNumbers;
};

function display_complex(re, im) {
    if(im === '0') return '' + re;
    if(re === 0) return '' + im + 'i';
    if(im < 0) return '' + re + im + 'i';
    return '' + re + '+' + im + 'i';
}

function addingComplexNumbers(first, second) {
    var num1;
    var num2;
    var first = parseInt(document.getElementById("firstComplexNumber").value) + parseInt(document.getElementById("secondComplexNumber").value);
    var second = parseInt(document.getElementById("thirdComplexNumber").value) + parseInt(document.getElementById("fourthComplexNumber").value);
    num1 = ImaginaryNumbers.transform(first);
    num2 = ImaginaryNumbers.transform(second);    
    var realNum = num1.realNum + num2.realNum;
    var imaginary = num1.imaginary + num2.imaginary;
    return document.getElementById("result8").innerHTML = display_complex(realNum, imaginary);
```

/*********************************************************/

```
HTML Code:
<form>
    <h1>Computing Imaginary Numbers</h1>
    <fieldset>    
        <p>Input the first real number : <input type="text" id="firstComplexNumber" /></p>
        <p>Input the first imaginary complex number: <input type="text" id="secondComplexNumber" /></p>
    </fieldset>
    <br>
    <fieldset>    
        <p>Input the second real number: <input type="text" id="thirdComplexNumber" /></p>
        <p>Input the second imaginary complex number : <input type="text" id="fourthComplexNumber" /></p>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="button" onclick="addingComplexNumbers()" value="Add">
    <input type="button" onclick="subtractingComplexNumbers()" value="Subtract">
    <input type="button" onclick="multiplyingComplexNumbers()" value="Multiply">
    <input type="button" onclick="dividingComplexNumbers()" value="Divide">

    <p>Result: <br>
        <span id="result8"></span>
    </p>
</form>
```

I used (2, -7) and (4,3) for the numbers but the program spits out 2+0i. Which isn't the answer. The correct answer is 6-4i. I'm not sure where I should be looking for to fix the computation. Any help would be nice!

Comment: `Input the third complex number` This isn't too clear - you might rename your inputs to something like "Input the real part of the first complex number", "Input the imaginary part of the first complex number", etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were initialising the imaginary numbers incorrectly, see changes the `addingComplexNumbers` function.

There are a few ways to fix this but I just went with passing the pairs into the `ImaginaryNumbers` constructor

```js
function ImaginaryNumbers(realNum, imaginary) {
  this.realNum = 0;
  this.imaginary = 0;
  this.realNum = (typeof realNum === 'undefined') ? this.realNum : parseFloat(realNum);
  this.imaginary = (typeof imaginary === 'undefined') ? this.imaginary : parseFloat(imaginary);
}

ImaginaryNumbers.transform = function(num) {
  var imaginaryNumbers;
  imaginaryNumbers = (num instanceof ImaginaryNumbers) ? num : imaginaryNumbers;
  imaginaryNumbers = (typeof num === 'number') ? new ImaginaryNumbers(num, 0) : num;
  return imaginaryNumbers;
};

function display_complex(re, im) {
  if (im === '0') return '' + re;
  if (re === 0) return '' + im + 'i';
  if (im < 0) return '' + re + im + 'i';
  return '' + re + '+' + im + 'i';
}

function addingComplexNumbers() {
  var first = new ImaginaryNumbers(parseInt(document.getElementById("firstComplexNumber").value) || 0, parseInt(document.getElementById("secondComplexNumber").value) || 0);
  var second = new ImaginaryNumbers(parseInt(document.getElementById("thirdComplexNumber").value) || 0, parseInt(document.getElementById("fourthComplexNumber").value) || 0);
  var realNum = first.realNum + second.realNum;
  var imaginary = first.imaginary + second.imaginary;
  var result = display_complex(realNum, imaginary);
  document.getElementById("result8").innerHTML = result;
  return result;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <h1>Computing Imaginary Numbers</h1>
  <fieldset>
    <p>Input the first real number : <input type="text" id="firstComplexNumber" /></p>
    <p>Input the first imaginary complex number: <input type="text" id="secondComplexNumber" /></p>
  </fieldset>
  <br>
  <fieldset>
    <p>Input the second real number: <input type="text" id="thirdComplexNumber"/></p>
    <p>Input the second imaginary complex number : <input type="text" id="fourthComplexNumber" /></p>
  </fieldset>
  <input type="button" onclick="addingComplexNumbers()" value="Add">
  <input type="button" onclick="subtractingComplexNumbers()" value="Subtract">
  <input type="button" onclick="multiplyingComplexNumbers()" value="Multiply">
  <input type="button" onclick="dividingComplexNumbers()" value="Divide">

  <p>Result: <br>
    <span id="result8"></span>
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You will need some error checking to make it more robust, but hope you're set in the right direction.